# Inconsistent PCA Results with Different Multiprocessing Settings in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, multiprocessing, cluster-computing, pca

I'm encountering an issue with PCA in `sklearn` while using `multiprocessing`. Specifically, the `reconstruction error` in `PCA` varies significantly based on the number of processes set in `Pool`. For instance, using `Pool(processes=4)` yields a small error (`np.abs(tmp_matrix-X_train).max()<1e-2)`, but increasing to `Pool(processes=5)` or higher results in a substantial error, with `np.abs(tmp_matrix-X_train).max()` averaging around `10` for each column. This behavior is observed while using the Intel `sklearnex` package.

I've tested various combinations and observed the following patterns:

- Stable (low error): `20 cpu`+`processes=1`,  `80 cpu`+`processes=1`,  `80 cpu`+`processes=4`,  `120 cpu`+`processes=5`
- Unstable (high error): `80 cpu`+`processes=5`,  `100 cpu`+`processes=5`,  `120 cpu`+`processes=5`(yes, 120+5 is unstable)

Here's the relevant portion of my code:

```py
from sklearnex import patch_sklearn
patch_sklearn()
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from functools import partial
from multiprocessing import Pool

def config_selection_single(df_entry: tuple, _some_arguments_indlucding_data_object):
    #some pre-processing code
    for some_iteration_condition:
        # some data processing and transformation to bound data non-NaN and between [-1e20,1e20]
        for another_iteration_condition:
            z_mean = X[train_cond][:].mean()    
            z_std = X[train_cond][:].std()+1e-10
            X_train = (X[train_cond][:]-z_mean) / z_std # X_train has shape ~ 2e4 X 50

            pca = PCA(n_components=20, svd_solver='full')
            p_model = pca.fit(X_train)
            Q = p_model.transform(X_train)
            tmp_matrix = p_model.inverse_transform(Q)
            if not np.allclose(Q,X_train.dot(p_model.components_.transpose())): # to compute reconstruction error.
                print("reconstruction error is huge!")
                print(np.abs(tmp_matrix-X_train).max())
        
config_selection_prtial = partial(config_selection_single, _some_arguments_indlucding_data_object)
with Pool(processes=4) as pool: # 4 is good, 5 and 6 are bad
    pool.map(config_selection_prtial, list(my_df.items()))
```

Unfortunately I could not find a small dataset demo that could reproduce the issue.

Any insights on why the number of processes affects PCA precision?

Comment: 1. it's not possible to help when there's no reproducible.
2. You're using sklearnex, not scikit-learn. So the issue is with the intel's implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[To answer my own question] It turns out to be a bug from `scikit-learn-intelex==2023.1.1`. When I udpate it to `scikit-learn-intelex==2024.0.1`, the result looks good.